# $ \left( \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |a_n|^2\right)^{5} \leq C \sum_{n_1\leq \cdots \leq n_5} |a_{n_1}|^2\cdots |a_{n_5}|^2 ?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

Let  $\{ a_n \} \subset  \mathbb C$.

> Can we say
>   $$ \left( \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |a_n|^2\right)^{5} \leq C \sum_{n_1\leq \cdots \leq n_5} |a_{n_1}|^2\cdots |a_{n_5}|^2 ?$$

(where $C$ is some constant, and $n_{i}\in \mathbb Z, i=1,...,5$, Assume RHS of the above inequality is finite.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$ \bigcup_{\sigma \in S_5} \{(n_1, \cdots, n_5) \in \Bbb{Z}^5 : n_{\sigma(1)} \leq \cdots \leq n_{\sigma(5)} \} = \Bbb{Z}^5, $$

where $S_5$ is the permutation group on $\{1,\cdots,5\}$. So

$$ \left( \sum_{n \in \Bbb{Z}} |a_n|^2 \right)^5
= \sum_{n_1, \cdots, n_5 \in \Bbb{Z}} |a_{n_1}|^2 \cdots |a_{n_5}|^2
\leq \sum_{\sigma \in S_5} \sum_{n_{\sigma(1)} \leq \cdots \leq n_{\sigma(5)}} |a_{n_1}|^2 \cdots |a_{n_5}|^2. $$

Upon relabeling, this gives the desired inequality with $C = 5!$.

Comment: @SL:Thanks. Why  $(\sum_{n_1} |a_{n_1}|^2) (\sum_{n_2} |a_{n_2}|^2) = (\sum_{n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb Z} |a_{n_1}|^2 |a_{n_2}|^2) ? $ And why  $\sum_{n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb Z} |a_{n_1}|^2 |a_{n_2}|^2) \leq 2! (\sum_{N_1\leq n_2} |a_{n_1}|^2 |a_{n_2}|^2)?$ Can you explain bit more? (I am unable to see how that $5!$ comes into the picture...)

Comment: @XYZ The first one is (intuitively) just distributive law. This is not quite different from $(a+b)(c+d) = ac+ad+bc+bd$, though infinite sum deserves an extra level of justification. In this case, you are summing non-negative values and hence everything is perfectly justified. For the second question, you have $$ \sum_{n_1, n_2 \in \Bbb{Z}} |a_{n_1}|^2|a_{n_2}|^2 \leq \sum_{n_1 \leq n_2} |a_{n_1}|^2|a_{n_2}|^2 + \sum_{n_2 \leq n_1} |a_{n_1}|^2|a_{n_2}|^2 $$ and  in the RHS, the second term is the same as the first term by relabeling indices.